# CircleCI DynamoDB Local

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, circleci

I'm trying to get it setup so CircleCI can use DynamoDB Local in my tests. I saw [this](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/how-to-install-dynamodb-local/2018/2) link about how to install DynamoDB Local on CircleCI but it looks outdated since they have now moved to new syntax with CircleCI 2.

How can I achieve this on the latest versions of CircleCI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adapt the old instructions into the new, using the build step 'command'. You will have to play with it a bit to get it to work as I'm not familiar with the software:

```
version: 2
jobs:
   build: 
     docker:
        - image: some-docker-image-that-has-java-or-even-dynamodb
     steps: 
        - stuff (usually 'checkout')  
        - run: 
           name: install java
           command: |
              apt-get update && apt-get install default-jre default-jdk
        - run:
           name: setup container
           command: |
              curl -k -L -o dynamodb-local.tgz http://dynamodb-local.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb_local_latest.tar.gz
              tar -xzf dynamodb-local.tgz
              java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb
```

Comment: Ok, now I'm using `- image: circleci/node:6.10` currently. I could be totally wrong but I don't believe that has Java. So how could I handle that?

Comment: I will update the answer with an example.But, you would install it the same way you would install it on any Ubuntu 14 system. `apt-get update && apt-get install package1 package2`

Comment: I would recommend using a docker image that has the things you need already. A search of docker hub almost always leads to finding someone else who has done 90% of your work for you.

Comment: I just don't have very much experience with Docker. Are you able to like combine Docker images? Like could I take a Java docker image and combine with a Node one? Or?

Comment: Getting an error with the install java run step `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
Exited with code 100`

Comment: Docker is very very flexible. I recommend you walk through some docker tutorials so you can get a feel for it and recognize it's power, and flexibility. Node and Java could be on just one container. The issue you just mentioned is a problem with whatever image you are using. I recommend using another one.

Comment: Ok, yeah I'm just using the default `circleci/node:6.10` image

Comment: Maybe instead just start with `- image: ubuntu:14.04` and build up your system from there. Installing java and dynamo as expressed above (as build run steps)

Comment: Ok so at that point I'd also have to install node. Will try that now.

Comment: So adding `- image: cnadiminti/dynamodb-local` under the node image seems to help. For some reason after about maybe 10 tests or so it fails saying `Uncaught Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000`. But that is another issue seems like. Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: Oh I just noticed this also, `Container cnadiminti/dynamodb-local Exited with code 137`

Comment: There are always changes that you need to make to accomodate a build system, I can't answer all of them in comments. I recommend playing with it a bit, reading the docs for CircleCI, then asking a new question here on SO when you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working end to end circleci `config.yml` file that works for a `nodejs` project version 8 and dynamodb local:

```
version: 2

references:
  container_config: &container_config
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8

    working_directory: ~/repo

  restore_repo: &restore_repo
    restore_cache:
      keys:
        - repo-v1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ .Revision }}
        - repo-v1-{{ .Branch }}
        - repo-v1-

  restore_npm_install: &restore_npm_install
    restore_cache:
      keys:
        - node_modules-v1-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
        # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
        - node_modules-v1-cache

  restore_dynamodb_local: &restore_dynamodb_local
    restore_cache:
      keys:
        - dynamodblocal-v1

jobs:
  checkout_code:
    <<: *container_config
    steps:
      - *restore_repo
      - checkout
      - save_cache:
          key: repo-v1-{{ .Branch }}-{{ .Revision }}
          paths:
            - .

  dynamodb_local_setup:
    <<: *container_config
    steps:
      - *restore_repo
      - *restore_dynamodb_local
      - run:
          name: "Downlad and install"
          command: |
            mkdir -p dynamodb_local
            cd dynamodb_local
            curl -k -L -o dynamodb-local.tgz http://dynamodb-local.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb_local_latest.tar.gz
            tar -xzf dynamodb-local.tgz
            cd ..
      - save_cache:
          key: dynamodblocal-v1
          paths:
            - ./dynamodb_local


  npm_install:
    <<: *container_config
    steps:
      - *restore_repo
      - *restore_npm_install
      - run:
          name: "npm install"
          command: npm install --update-binary
      - save_cache:
          key: node_modules-v1-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          paths:
            - ./node_modules

  lint:
    <<: *container_config
    steps:
      - *restore_repo
      - *restore_npm_install
      - run:
          name: "Linting"
          command: npm run lint -- --format junit -o reports/junit/js-lint-results.xml

  test:
    <<: *container_config
    steps:
      - *restore_repo
      - *restore_npm_install
      - *restore_dynamodb_local
      - run:
          name: "Test suite execution"
          # Because "CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config"
          # AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY are mandatory to access dynamodblocal, you can set fake ones on circleci project configuration
          command: |
            sudo apt-get install default-jre --assume-yes
            java -Djava.library.path=./dynamodb_local/DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar ./dynamodb_local/DynamoDBLocal.jar -port 2018 -inMemory &
            ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --ci --testResultsProcessor="jest-junit" --collectCoverage --coverageReporters="lcov"
          environment:
            JEST_JUNIT_OUTPUT: "reports/junit/js-test-results.xml"
      - run:
          name: "Report to codecov.io"
          command: ./node_modules/codecov/bin/codecov

      - store_test_results: #along with linting results
          path: reports/junit

      - store_artifacts:
          path: reports/junit

      - store_artifacts:
          path: coverage

workflows:
  version: 2
  main:
    jobs:
      - checkout_code
      - dynamodb_local_setup:
          requires:
            - checkout_code
      - npm_install:
          requires:
            - checkout_code
      - lint:
          requires:
            - npm_install
      - test:
          requires:
            - npm_install
            - dynamodb_local_setup
```

Last up to date gist https://gist.github.com/HerveNivon/81563806680c9aab1e36c589e9ea7622

Comment: Normally on Stack Overflow just posting a link in an answer is not really allowed in the guidelines. The question should be answered within the answer itself and links can be used to provide extra information.

Comment: Inline `config.yml` sir :)

Comment: In August 2018 [Amazon announced](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/08/use-amazon-dynamodb-local-more-easily-with-the-new-docker-image/) new [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local/) with Amazon DynamoDB Local onboard.