# CircleCI script to test against DynamoDB Local Fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, circleci

We have a CircleCI script that manages our deployment. I wanted to allow DynamoDB local to run so that we could test our DynamoDB requests. I've tried following the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404898/circleci-dynamodb-local), [here](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/how-to-install-dynamodb-local/2018) and [here](https://medium.com/@jameshamann/circle-ci-and-dynamodb-6db3c82f2f6a). I've also tries using the DynamoDB local image from Docker Hub, [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local). This is the closest I've gotten.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  setup-dynamodb:
    docker:
    - image: openjdk:15-jdk
    steps:
    - setup_remote_docker:
        version: 18.06.0-ce
   - run:
        name: run-dynamodb-local
        background: true
        shell: /bin/bash
        command: |
          curl -k -L -o dynamodb-local.tgz http://dynamodb-local.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dynamodb_local_latest.tar.gz
          tar -xzf dynamodb-local.tgz
          java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -port 8000 -sharedDb
  check-failed:
    docker:
    - image: golang:1.14.3
    steps:
    - checkout
    - setup_remote_docker:
        version: 18.06.0-ce
    - attach_workspace:
        at: /tmp/app/workspace
    - run:
        name: Install dockerize
        shell: /bin/bash
        command: |
          yum -y update && \
           yum -y install wget && \
            yum install -y tar.x86_64 && \
            yum clean all
          wget https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize/releases/download/$DOCKERIZE_VERSION/dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz && \ 
            tar -C /usr/local/bin -xzvf dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz && \
            rm dockerize-linux-amd64-$DOCKERIZE_VERSION.tar.gz
        environment:
          DOCKERIZE_VERSION: v0.3.0
    - run:
        name: Wait for Local DynamoDB
        command: dockerize -wait tcp://localhost:8000 -timeout 1m
    - run:
        name: checkerr
        shell: /bin/bash
        command: |
          ls -laF /tmp/app/workspace/
          for i in $(seq 1 2); do
            f=$(printf "failed%d.txt" $i)
            value=$(</tmp/app/workspace/$f)
            if [[ "$value" != "nil" ]]; then
              echo "$f = $value"
              exit 1
            fi
          done
```

The problem I'm having is that all my tests are failing with error message `dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8000: connect: connection refused`. I'm not sure why this is happening. Do I need to expose the port from the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, the first job is totally seperate to second job.

In fact, you don't need the first one, and adjust second one as below

```
check-failed:
  docker:
  - image: golang:1.14.3
  - image: amazon/dynamodb-local
steps:
- setup_remote_docker:
...
...
```

By the way, you don't need install dynamodb every time, you can run as container as well

Comment: Okay, this worked for me. Although I had to put it on the build steps that I didn't include here because those actually ran the tests and the `check_failed` step merely pushed the results to slack.

Comment: As followup, I started having 137 errors so I tried adding the entrypoint, `java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -Xmx256m -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -port 8000`, which fixed the 137 errors but now I'm getting the connection-refused erorrs again. Do you have any ideas?